# Unable to read Gantner RFID wristband from my gym

Tags: rfid

I have an RFID wristband from my gym, of which I know they use the Gantner systems, so I assume it must be this (however I can't be sure, but it looks exactly like the black one on that website):

- https://www.gantner.com/product/electronic-wristband-with-rfid-gat-chipband-20/
- https://www.gantner.com/download/585/?v=586

The second link (pdf) states the following specs:

- Frequency: 13.56 MHz (MIFARE®)
- Unique number: 7 byte
- RFID chip: “F7“ = MIFARE® 7byte

**I am unable to read the tag via my Android phone using the "NFC tools" app as well as with my Arduino + RFID-RC522 reader**.

The reader used at the gym is one built into either one of of those:

- https://www.gantner.com/product/ticketing-terminal-gat-access-6600/
- https://www.gantner.com/product/access-control-terminal-for-turnstiles-gat-access-6350/

**However: I ordered an RFID wristband (SILA09 MIFARE® Classic 1K; ISO Standard: 14443A) from Amazon** that looks the same like the Gantner:

https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07SMBGY6J/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

and **I can read this just fine** with both my Android as well as RFID-RC522 reader.

**So, I'm really wondering what the difference between the two might be?**

(I'm fairly new to RFID.)

Additional note: I also have a 125 khz reader and I can confirm it doesn't read the Gantner wristband either, just to make sure it's not a 125 khz tag.

Comment: it is possible that the band only resonds after a particular code is received

Comment: the documentation suggests that the gantner tags are some kind of mifare. is your RFID-RC522 able to read other mifare tags?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, my reader can read Mifare Classic and Mifare Plus, i.e. my credit card, debit card, other tags I ordered on Amazon (also Mifare Classic, the one I linked in my post), can be read just fine. I need to read up on the mechanism that jsotola mentioned, how you can restrict a response based on received code. Good hint, wasn't aware of it.